# How do I specify a round parenthesis below some text?

Tags: brackets

I need something similar to `\underbrace` but instead of curly brackets, I would like to have normal round horizontal paranthesis below my text. Similar to `\textbottomtiebar` but spanning the whole text.

How do I achieve this with tex?

Comment: Perhaps a `minipage`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also: [How do I specify a round parenthesis above some text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39430/how-do-i-specify-a-round-parenthesis-above-some-text) for another solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an implementation of such thing you wanted done entirely in TeX (no tikz, no mathtools, no pstricks, nothing extra, etc):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\underparen#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \upparenfill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\def\upparenfill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\underparen{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$
\end{document}
```

Here is another solution using graphicx package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\myboxwidth
\newdimen\myboxheight
\newdimen\myboxdepth
\def\underparen#1{%
\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}%
\myboxwidth\wd\z@%
\myboxheight\ht\z@%
\myboxdepth\dp\z@%
\mathop{\box\z@}\limits_{\kern-\myboxdepth\resizebox{\myboxwidth}{\myboxheight}{\rotatebox{90}{(}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\underparen{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second solution has obvious problems if it's used inline: the baseline of underbraced text and that of the surrounding text don't match.

Comment: I edited second solution.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a `TikZ`-based solution (in fact, this solution can be viewed as the `TikZ` version of the `PS-Tricks` solution provided by Werner); the idea is to place a node at the beginning of the text and another one at the end, and then draw a curved line between those two nodes; the optional argument of `\myunderline` gives control over the attributes used to draw the line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\myunderline[2][]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (a) {};#2%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (b) {};
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=315,in=225,distance=0.2cm]
    \draw[#1] (a.center) to (b.center);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\myunderline{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\myunderline[red]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\myunderline[blue,dashed]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might add that you have to compile twice for the lines to show up.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good point!  That also applies to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a slight  variant of Gonzalo's answer that uses the [calligraphy](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) package to style the parenthetical line a little more like a parenthesis.

Here's the result:

[image: parentheses under text]

Unfortunately, dashed lines are no longer possible.  The only allowed modification is to the colour (though one could make the thickness configurable).

Here's the code, blatantly adapted from Gonzalo's answer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{calligraphy}

\newcommand\myunderline[2][black]{%
  \rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=.5ex] \coordinate (a);#2%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=.5ex] \coordinate (b);
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[thick,/pgf/calligraphy/pen colour=#1,decorate,decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis}] (b) to (a);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\myunderline{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\myunderline[red]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\myunderline[blue]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

(I should warn any readers of this that the calligraphy package is still in development and so should be considered at "alpha" level.  Also, you need the `spath` library which is available from the same site.)

Comment: Torbjørn's comment on Gonzalo's answer also applies: you have to compile twice for the lines to show up, or to notice changes in location of the text.

Answer (score 6):

There are some other alternatives to `\underbrace`, like `\underbracket` from the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). However, for optimal control, you could use a graphics package to draw an arc underneath your text.

The following minimal example shows the difference between `\underbrace`, `\underbracket`, [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa)'s `\textbottomtiebar` and the newly created `\textbottomtie` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\newcounter{tbtcntr}% \textbottomtie counter
\newcommand{\textbottomtie}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{tbtcntr}% For uniqueness
  \psDefBoxNodes{tbt\thetbtcntr}{#2}% typeset contents
  \ncarc[linewidth=0.5pt,arcangle=-5,linestyle=solid,#1]{-}{tbt\thetbtcntr:bl}{tbt\thetbtcntr:br}% arc
}
\begin{document}
$\underbracket{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
$\underbrace{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
\textbottomtiebar{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog} \par
\textbottomtie{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}
\end{document}
```

The construction relies on `\ncarc` from the [`pstricks` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) and sets an arc at an angle of `-5`, width of `0.5pt` and `solid` line style by default. Alternative, all the rich features of `pstricks` can be passed to `\ncarc` via the optional parameters of `\textbottomtie[<options>]{...}`. For example, passing `linecolor=blue` will typeset a blue line, while `offset=-5pt` will drop the tie by `5pt` vertically. You can also override the default values by merely respecifying then (for example, using `linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed` produces a `1pt` dashed tie).

Nodes are marked using [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) and inserts the arc (or tie) tips at the bottom left (`bl`) and bottom right (`br`) of the text argument. If need be, it is possible to extend this to work also with larger text groups, like paragraphs and such, using a `minipage`, for example.

Since this uses `pstricks`, your compile sequence should be `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or `xelatex`. Also, if using an arc is not satisfactory, you could use any one of the many node connection alternatives; just view the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) (**VII Node Connections**, p 58).

Note that you might have to do some vertical correction below `\textbottomtie` to avoid it overwriting text below it.