# How do I specify a round parenthesis above some text?

Tags: brackets

How can I draw a horizontal round parenthesis *above* some text? [How do I specify a round parenthesis below some text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36097/how-do-i-specify-a-round-parenthesis-below-some-text) explains how to do it below text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`abraces` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces) under the `overload` package option provides this when using `\overbrace[L1R]` or `\underbrace[l1r]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{abraces}% http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces
\begin{document}
$\overbrace[L1R]{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par \medskip
$\underbrace[l1r]{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
\end{document}
```

---

#### Original answer:

Here is a modified version of `\overbrace` in the form of `\overfence`, which should provide what you're after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

% \overfence definition
\let\overfence\overbrace % \overfence is similar to \overbrace
\let\downfencefill\downbracefill % match components of \overbrace
\patchcmd{\overfence}{\downbracefill}{\downfencefill}{}{}% patch \overfence...
\patchcmd{\downfencefill}{\braceru \bracelu}{}{}{}%... and \downfencefill

% \underfence definition
\let\underfence\underbrace % \underfence is similar to \underbrace
\let\upfencefill\upbracefill % match components of \underbrace
\patchcmd{\underfence}{\upbracefill}{\upfencefill}{}{}% patch \underfence...
\patchcmd{\upfencefill}{\bracerd \braceld}{}{}{}%... and \upfencefill

\begin{document}
$\overbracket{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
$\overbrace{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
$\overfence{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par \medskip
$\underbracket{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
$\underbrace{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$ \par
$\underfence{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}$
\end{document}
```

In fact, since `\overfence` duplicates the behaviour of `\overbrace`, you can even add stuff to it since it's typeset as a `\mathop` with `\limits`. For example:

[image]

```
$\overfence{\textrm{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}}^{\mbox{\scriptsize Because the dog is really lazy.}}$
```